# Need help debugging switchChanged method

Tags: xcode, ios4

Am getting error ("switchChanged" undeclared) in the implementation file, but can't find the problem. Can you help me?

TIA

ViewController.m

```
#import "Control_FunViewController.h"



@implementation Control_FunViewController

@synthesize nameField;
@synthesize numberField;
@synthesize sliderLabel;
@synthesize leftSwitch;
@synthesize rightSwitch;
@synthesize doSomethingButton;

-(IBAction)sliderChanged:(id)sender
{
    UISlider *slider = (UISlider *)sender;
    int progressAsInt = (int)(slider.value + 0.5f);
    NSString *newText = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d",progressAsInt];
    sliderLabel.text = newText;
    [newText release];
}

-(IBAction)textFieldDoneEditing:(id)sender
{
    [sender resignFirstResponder];
}

-(IBAction)backgroundTap:(id)sender
{
    [nameField resignFirstResponder];
    [numberField resignFirstResponder];
}

-(IBAction)toggleControls:(id)sender
{
    if ([sender selectedSegmentIndex] == kSwitchesSegmentIndex)
    {
        leftSwitch.hidden = NO;
        rightSwitch.hidden = NO;
        doSomethingButton.hidden = YES;
    }
    else {
        leftSwitch.hidden =YES;
        rightSwitch.hidden =YES;
        doSomethingButton.hidden = NO;
    }
-(IBAction)switchChanged:(id)sender
    {
        UISwitch *whichSwitch = (UISwitch *)sender;
        BOOL setting = whichSwitch.isOn;
        [leftSwitch setOn:setting animated:YES];
        [rightSwitch setOn:setting animated:YES];
    }
-(IBAction)buttonPressed
    {
        //TODO: Implement Action Sheet and Alert
    }
}





/*
// The designated initializer. Override to perform setup that is required before the view is loaded.
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
*/

/*
// Implement loadView to create a view hierarchy programmatically, without using a nib.
- (void)loadView {
}
*/


/*
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
*/


/*
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
*/

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [nameField release];
    [numberField release];
    [sliderLabel release];
    [leftSwitch release];
    [rightSwitch release];
    [doSomethingButton release];
     [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#define kSwitchesSegmentIndex   0

@interface Control_FunViewController : UIViewController {
    UITextField *nameField;
    UITextField *numberField;
    UILabel *sliderLabel;
    UISwitch *leftSwitch;
    UISwitch *rightSwitch;
    UIButton *doSomethingButton;
}

@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UITextField *nameField;
@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UITextField *numberField;
@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UILabel *sliderLabel;
@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UISwitch *leftSwitch;
@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UISwitch *rightSwitch;
@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UIButton *doSomethingButton;

-(IBAction)textFieldDoneEditing:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)backgroundTap:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)sliderChanged:(id)sender; 
-(IBAction)toggleControls:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)switchChanged:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)buttonPressed;


@end
```

Answer (score 0):

The colon (:) is part of the name of the method, but you haven't included it in the error message. It may be that you just forgot, but if you're calling -switchChanged (no colon) from somewhere, or if you connected a control using the action -switchChanged (no colon), that's the problem. Perhaps you added the colon and sender parameter later on?

Comment: The colon was left out of the error message; that was not my mistake leaving it out. It is what Xcode returned to me. As far as I can tell, I have included all colons in the switchChanged: method, and I have also included it in the header, so I can't figure out where the error is.

Comment: This is a compile time error, right? If it were happening at run time, you'd get an error about an unrecognized selector. If that's the case, doesn't the compiler indicate the line where the problem occurs?

Comment: Found the problem. The method above (toggleControls) was missing a closing bracket, which caused the problem. Once that was fixed, everything compiled OK.